# Set a cookie for a website with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Theoretically I have a cookie for a different website (not my own). Is it possible to take the cookie I have at hand, and some how set it in my browser for a different website? This is possible with google chrome extensions, though if I were to do it strictly with javascript, (on a mobile device), how would I? Any Website references would be great aswell. Thanks!

Comment: No, cookies are always associated with a specific domain.

Comment: cross domain cookies! my eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do it with client side JavaScript only.